# Conditional categories

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions, mediawiki-templates

I'm using a template `{{MyTemplate|foo}}` which consists of the following code:

```
{{#switch: {{{1}}}
 | foo = [[Category:Foo]]
 | bar = [[Category:Bar]]
 | #default = [[Category:Unknown]]
}}
```

When I'm using it on a page, the categories show up nicely as wished at the bottom of that page. But unfortunately inside of that category-page (Category:Foo for example) the page doesn't show up.

If I add `[[Category:Foo]]` manually to that page, the page shows up in the Foo-category-page.

Any suggestions why this doesn't work via the template?

Answer (score 4):

Does the template page that contain the previous code appear under `Unknown` category?. If yes, then any page contain that template must appear in it's category. You may just have to clear cache, and wait few seconds if you have a large wiki.

Make sure that foo & bar categories are not hidden in your wiki. See this: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Categories#Hidden_categories

**EDIT**

Also, try one of these solutions, which can do the same goal:

```
{{#switch: {{{1}}}
 | foo = [[Category:Foo]]
 | bar = [[Category:Bar]]
 | #default = [[Category:Unknown]]
}}
```

OR

```
{{#ifeq: {{{1}}} | foo | [[Category:Foo]] | {{#ifeq: {{{1}}} | bar | [[Category:Bar]] |  [[Category:Unknown]]}} }}
```

Comment: They did appear under the unknown-category. I fixed that (includeonly-embracing). The categories are not hidden. I cleared the cache of the category-page and the template page, but no change: All pages still appear under the unknown-category.

Comment: You mean when you open Unknown-category page, you find all pages using that template inside of it?

Comment: Exactly, they all appear there!

Comment: Now they do not appear in the Unknown-category anymore but they still do not appear in the foo- or bar-category. :-(

Answer (score 0):

Do you run the jobqueue on your wiki? Linkstables are updated asynchronously and not at page save time.

https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Job_queue

https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:RunJobs.php

Comment: Yes, this runs automatically every two hours and updates the categories that are not added conditionally. However the conditional-categories don't work.

Answer (score 0):

Cant understand the description to your problem, but anyway, it seems like you could achieve the same goal by:

```
{{#vardefine: my_category |wow}}
[[Category: {{#ifeq: {{#var:my_category}}| default| unknown| {{#var:my_category}} }} ]]
```

Which adds this category to the page,
In my opinion, you should use switch when you are adding category in any case but also decide *not* to add category in another case.

If you are adding category in all cases, you can write as i wrote above, or export the final category to another variable and use it inside the category.

As for your problem, you can use "?action=purge" for this page, if that wont work, write here some more info.